# TypeError: mnemonic.computeSeed is not a function

Tags: javascript, web3js, ethers.js

This is my code
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCKGy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HC9S.png)
and this is my error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLWUg.png)

I tried to change from HDNodeWallet to HDNode but still no result
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HZv4.png)
This is the result I've received when I tried to change from HDNodeWallet to HDNode

Comment: Please check out: "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just revert to an older version of the ethers library. I think. In my own case i used the version 5.7.2 and it worked.
This is my code

```
    const ethers = require('ethers');

    // Generate a random mnemonic (12-word phrase)
    const mnemonic = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().mnemonic.phrase;

    // Create a wallet from the mnemonic
    const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);

    // Retrieve the private key
    const privateKey = wallet.privateKey;

    // Retrieve the public key
    const publicKey = wallet.address;

    console.log('Mnemonic:', mnemonic);
    console.log('Private Key:', privateKey);
    console.log('Public Key (Address):', publicKey);
```

The error I was having was this

```
    const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
                         ^
    TypeError: ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic is not a function
```

Till I reverted to the version 5.7.2

```
    npm i ethers@5.7.2
```

Might not be the ultimate solution but it worked

Answer (score 0):

ethers v6 has a [different API](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/6ee1a5f8bb38ec31fa84c00aae7f091e1d3d6837/src.ts/wallet/hdwallet.ts#L376).

You need to create a `Mnemonic` instance from the mnemonic phrase and then create a `HDNodeWallet`

```
import { HDNodeWallet, Mnemonic } from 'ethers';

const mnemonicInstance = Mnemonic.fromPhrase(mnemonic);
const firstAccount     = HDNodeWallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonicInstance, `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`);
```